# OnSwipe in MotionLayout scene transition

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-jetpack-compose, android-motionlayout

I have a mapView inside my fragment and in the same fragment xml file I have a fragmentContainer,
Inside that fragment container I have a motion layout full screen. I have a guideline at 75% and all views are below that, giving it a feel of a bottom sheet on top of the mapView.
Now when I swipe up or down I want to animate the views using transitions but I also want the user to drag the maps. The problem is that onSwipe is conflicting with the mapDrag, User is unable to use maps. I am unable to restrict onSwipe to just the motionLayout views.

I tried

```
limitBoundsTo
```

but it is not working.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.